# how i can work programaticly with spell effect in game

Tags: animation, graphics, 3d, unity-game-engine, game-engine

how i can work programaticly with spell effect in game

i have a effect look like [this spell effect](http://www.google.ae/imgres?safe=active&sa=X&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=Xv6La47UUD8KfM%3a&imgrefurl=http://blueberrytotem.wordpress.com/tag/chain-heal/&docid=cJA480TeNAo5tM&imgurl=http://blueberrytotem.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/138192.jpg&w=690&h=362&ei=Bl7oUsWrKIzmoAS_-oDwCg&zoom=1&ved=0COcBEIQcMC8&iact=rc&dur=3452&page=3&start=45&ndsp=23)

i want to know how i can change the cale of the spell .
like  change color in distance 
or when u run some this effect goes to transparent and after 10 sec  go to fade

---

or 
[look at this spell and wepon in this pic](http://www.google.ae/imgres?start=182&safe=active&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=EBAgmW_ytkfoPM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.wikihow.com/Play-a-Priest-in-World-of-Warcraft&docid=LiuIMu5FMZR4yM&imgurl=http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/5/5e/Play-a-Priest-in-World-of-Warcraft-Step-2.jpg/670px-Play-a-Priest-in-World-of-Warcraft-Step-2.jpg&w=670&h=503&ei=GF_oUsb3MYeAogTY0YKIBg&zoom=1&ved=0CAsQhBwwAjjIAQ&iact=rc&dur=310&page=9&ndsp=25)   like when you have a small wepon  and u add a animation effect on it ( like fire  or ice effect )

how you change the animation base on the size of the wepon

i have no idea how i have to implement that

thanks in advance

**[Edit by Spektre] acording to comments I would change the question text to something like this:**

- I need/want to program a spell effect visualization for game or whatever ...
- what are the common/usual approaches to do this (algorithms,graphics techniques)
- want to implement Ice/Fire/??? effects
- in form of rays/waves/field/cones...
- ideally by a single configurable effect routine (I guess this)
- also what are the exact names for some of these effects so I can do a search for them myself
- I want to use Unity3D environment

this is  the way i want to know   how i can make an dynamic spell effect

Comment: your question is little vague (I think thats why the down-votes go) please edit your question a little add some code of your base spell effect so we can see how it works (there are dozens of ways to create such effects so we have to see which you actually use) so someone can help you with your problem. Also post image of used textures so we can see if the spell color is done by code or image or both ...

Comment: @ spektre   you can explain how many way we can implement  effect to a game  so i do serch  on the internet  by the keyword ?

Comment: there are infinite posibilities so no. your question suggest you have working effect and want to change it to be custom size/color/duration ... so for starters you should post the code for that effect. If you have none then reformulate the question that you are searching for algorithm to mach this graphical effect ... and post what you have already done and what is wrong with it

Comment: @Spektre   ya i dont have the way of doing it and  this is my answer   i just want some keyword so i can search it on the internet because i dont have good english so i need some keyword  for effect  ------one is  ice effect  in 2D  anothere one is  flame arond a 2D object  -- anothere one is  hot air effect   -- i dont have an keyword for them and more  effect that i cant explain  and i havent enugh  ++ so i cant add picture on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are many approaches for this. I am no expert in the field and not a **Unity3D** user so I stick to basics:

1. **particle system**

   It is an engine which visualize particles (many small moving objects). It is used for many effects like: rocket throttle,fire,lighting,changing glow,and many more. The trick is the use of blending so each particle is usually semi transparent ball. More transparent on the outside and more solid on the inside. When you draw more particles close together they blend to the desired continuous effect.

   This can be done by single textured `QUAD` or `TRIANGLE`. The texture can be white color with alpha channel coded transparency so color of the effect can be coded without change in the texture. Color,size and movement patterns can differ to each other and also with time. These three parameters define the effect look for example you want to cast a electric ray from caster to target so the movement pattern is `LINE`. Now distort that line a little by some random numbers so the `LINE` becomes a `POLYLINE` and on the Vertex of this `POLYLINE` you can sometimes free a particle in random direction with limited duration so it will be like some sparks (do not forget to lower their size in time so they dissipate). Also you have to experiment with the speed and size/color of the main particle stream along the `POLYLINE` so it looks right. Some effect need to combine few different particle streams together.

   **Search keywords:** particle system,RGBA texture,blending,interpolation

   [image: partickle system effec]

   this picture is taken from the link posted in the question. It is a nice example of two particle systems. Yellow straight `LINE` particle stream and green `POLYLINE` particle stream. Also some green sparks around the main stream are present.
2. **texture animation**

   You can have a little cyclic movie (image by image) in an array of textures so you draw the texture on an plane (usually single `QUAD` or `TRIANGLE`) and change the texture after some time to the next , and usually after last go from first again. You can also use `BLEND`ing or `STENCIL` techniques to draw only the effect area. If the textures are white (colorless) then the color can be modulated by code. This is mostly used for explosions, fire,...

   [image: texplosion texture movie]

   this is simple explosion movie example it is not a cyclic animation so after last frame the effect stops (explosion has finite duration)

Comment: Omg this is exactly what i need  now i can search for advanced thing on this field  thx you really  --  one thing  why  i cant ask more question ?

Comment: You can but when you ask a vague one which answer could cover entire library of books than it is a bad one ... try to ask specific thing exactly what you need... you can edit and add a new subquestion at any time ... but make sure to add a comment so the users in comment list will have a notice of change

Comment: What do you mean by banned to ask question? ... you should be able to create new questions any time. If I remember correctly you just cannot create new comment thread but after someone add comment you can continue

Comment: Your question could be put on hold/closed or deleted then you are forbidden to do some things with it until its voted to reopen but your question is still valid so this is not the case

Comment: but i am on banned and cant ask any question from my acc  how its poosible ?   ( when i  click ask a question   its say   " Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. " )  so what i have to do ----- and Spektre  we cant talk in any chat form system  if its no problem for you ?

Comment: well I am still new to SO so I didnt even know that you can be banned for down-voting first question ... look here and read it completely http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146416/236640 it suggest that you earn some points by contributing. btw if you get a new account in any StackExchange site you gain +100 rep if I remember correctly. also you can allways create new account and be careful for question text. I usually get down-voted by users that do not know what I am writing about or when i have something wrong. (for example almost all downvote questions of mine had +3 or more votes before)

Comment: @Sparktre   Thx  can you message me on my  hangout  so we can chat ? is it possible i ask 2 time before :D  if possible i can ask more question and we can chat there

Comment: rly thanks from spektre  can rate  plus on this post so i can post more game question  ? thanks