# I have a black texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, opengl-compat

This is my first time working with textures in OpenGL, although I've been studying it for 4 months now. And when I try to load a texture (Just an image with a square) I get just a black square.\

My texture load code:

```
  byte[] pixelData = new byte[0];
        try {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(TEXTURE_FILES));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos);
            baos.flush();
            pixelData = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(pixelData);
        int texId = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_FALSE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, 500, 500, 0,
                GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);

        return texId;
```

I tried loading the texture with a simpler method, but it did not work. Also I tried another image or to place the texture not in my jar file

Texture show code:

```
                glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                glVertex2f(-1, -1);
                glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                glVertex2f(1, -1);
                glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                glVertex2f(1, 1);
                glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                glVertex2f(-1, 1);
                glEnd();
                glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

My opengl paramters:

```
        glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glColorMask (true, true, true, true);
        glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
```

I also read many other tips from this forum, but they are useless for me too

My result:
[image: result]

I tried also to run it on another computer with a different video card, but the result remains the same

Comment: `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_FALSE)` makes not any sense. `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP` is not a valid texture parameter.

Comment: @Rabbid76  if I remove it the problem still remains

Comment: Yes I know, that doesn't solve the issue, it was just a side note. I don't know whats wrong in your code. It seem to be the same issue in all of your last questions.

Comment: @Rabbid76 As I can see, you have a lot of experience working with OpenGL. Do not know what is my problem with a black texture?
I can’t solve this problem for the fourth day. I visited over 100 different pages in several different forums, but nothing from there helped me ...

Comment: I've a lot of OpenGL knowledge, but my Java knowledge is poor. I can't see any issue in the OpenGL instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly th issue is reading the png file:

> ```
> BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(TEXTURE_FILES));
> ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> ImageIO.write(bi, "png", baos);
> baos.flush();
> pixelData = baos.toByteArray();
> baos.close();
> ```

I've found a cde snippet ([LWJGL3 Texture](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5559.0)) where the file is read in a loop:

```java
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(TEXTURE_FILES);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int read1 = is.read();
while (read1 != -1) { 
    baos.write(read1);
    read1 = is.read();
}
byte[] pixelData= baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(pixelData);
```

Alternatively a `PNGDecoder` is used:
(See also [Load a PNG file with pure OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399242/load-a-png-file-with-pure-opengl) and [Loading PNG images with TWL's PNGDecoder](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Loading_PNG_images_with_TWL's_PNGDecoder.html))

```java
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(TEXTURE_FILES);
PNGDecoder decoder = new PNGDecoder(in);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3*decoder.getWidth()*decoder.getHeight());
decoder.decode(byteBuffer, decoder.getWidth()*3, PNGDecoder.Format.RGB);
byteBuffer.flip();
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me. There are still a few problems, but they are absolutely not connected with this. The main thing is that I see my texture. I didn’t think that OpenGL requires special loading of textures.